# Finding the last empty row, excluding header

Tags: excel, vba

I've got the following column in a table

[image]

and I've got the following code

```
   lrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row      
      
   Range_to_delete = "Y2:Y" & lrow2
                             
   Range(Range_to_delete).Clear
```

My problem right now is that sometimes there are no numbers on column Y, therefore when that code executes it deletes the header too, is there a way I can modify the following line of code so that it excludes row 1 somehow?

```
lrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row
```

Note: I can't say if lrow2 = 1 then skip this part because then that messes up some of my other conditions that I use later on.

Comment: `Range_to_delete = "Y2:Y" & Application.MAX(lrow2,2)`

Comment: Check Lrow2 before.  As @Wizhi says

Comment: @Sam It's never to late to get acustomed to explicitly *fully qualify* all range references to make sure to address actually your targeted worksheet, not any sheet currently active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any values, you don't need to delete anything. So maybe this can work:

```
   lrow2 = Cells(Rows.Count, 25).End(xlUp).Row      
   
   If lrow2 > 1 Then 
       Range_to_delete = "Y2:Y" & lrow2
                             
       Range(Range_to_delete).Clear
   End if
```